# How to specify keys in Apache Spark while joining two datasets

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am loading two files as below -

```
  f1 = sc.textFile("s3://testfolder1/file1")
  f2 = sc.textFile("s3://testfolder2/file2")
```

This load operation gives me list of tuples. For each row one tuple is created.

Schema for file1 and file2 is as below -

```
  f1 (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
  f2 (x,y,z,a,b,c,f,r,u)
```

I want to join these two datasets based on fields a,b,c.  I did some research and found that there below method that might be useful.

```
  rdd.keyBy(func)
```

However, I can't find a easy way to specify keys and join two datasets.
Can anyone demonstrate how to do it without using DataFrames ?  Use of SparkSQL is okay but if it can be done without SparkSQL that would be best.

Answer (score 2):

*This load operation gives me list of tuples*

No, it will give you an `RDD[String]`.

You can take the string, and convert it to anything you want.

For your use case, you can convert each line to ((a,b,c),(d,e,f,g,h,i))

```
f1 = sc.textFile("s3://testfolder1/file1").map { line =>
val a::b::c::d::e::d::f::g::h::i::other = line.split(YOUR_DELIMITER).toList
((a,b,c),(d,e,f,g,h,i))
}

f2 = sc.textFile("s3://testfolder1/file1").map { line =>
val a::b::c::d::e::d::f::g::h::i::other = line.split(YOUR_DELIMITER).toList
((a,b,c),(d,e,f,g,h,i))
}
```

and then, `f1.join(f2)` should just work.